# How to add for loop values to an arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an activity where in the values are fetched via JSON. The `for` loop is run. I am receiving all the values present in the fetched object from JSON. However, I want to append all the values to an `ArrayList`, i.e. `image_urls`. Could any one please help me?

```
public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static String url = "http://www.ttt.com/album_pro/array_to_encode";

    JSONArray folio = null;
    ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> image_urls = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            // Log.v("URL",json.toString());

            JSONObject seo = json.getJSONObject("SEO");
            // Log.v("seo",seo.toString());
            JSONArray folio = seo.getJSONArray("Folio");
            Log("ARRAY-FOLIO0" + folio);

            JSONArray image_urls1 = new JSONArray();
            String s1 = seo.getString("Folio");
            for (int i = 0; i < folio.length(); i++) {
                String m = folio.getString(i);
                Log.v("M" + i, m);
                image_urls.add(folio.getString(i) + ",");
                Log("JSON-ARRAY-->" + image_urls.add(folio.getString(i)));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void Log(String string) {
        Log.v("SEO-TEST", string);

    }
}
```

Following is the logcat response I am getting

```
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M0(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_a_grade_motor_school.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_11.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M1(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arcticterntt_folio_portfolio_abc_tarps.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M2(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_able_scale.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M3(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_accent_aluminum_windows.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M4(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_access_health.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M5(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_acmeda__zipscreen.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_11.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M6(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_aditya_birla_minerals.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M7(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_advanced_corporate_badges.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M8(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_aerotech_fans.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/M9(3241): http://www.tt.com/media/imagepath/portfolio_images/http_arctictern.tt_folio_portfolio_agriculture_victoria_services_.html_a_poftfolio_2013_01_10.png
03-05 13:58:25.948: V/SEO-TEST(3241): JSON-ARRAY-->true
```

Comment: Use StringBuilder and append every element, and then use toString() function to get full string.

Comment: Move the JSON processing logic to AsyncTask. You can't have networking on UI thread that too in onCreate() method. Move the code to Async Task and call the Async task in onResume() method

Comment: post your json String with question .  are u getting any error with current code?

Comment: @Big.Child : Thnx.The data is getting appended.But according to the requirement in my app i need to have an array of the string.Could you please guide

Comment: So, how I understand you need string array of appended values and not just one full string, right ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<folio.size(); ++i) {
    values.add(folio.getString(i));
}
```

Comment: I tried doing the same, but iam getting the append test as "true" in the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Your log cat was printing true because you had put `"image_urls.add(folio.getString(i))"` in your message and this line will return true if item is added successfully..
    Please check now as follows

```
 ArrayList<String > image_urls1 = new JSONArray(); //Use arrayList here
                String s1 = seo.getString("Folio");
                for (int i = 0; i < folio.length(); i++) {
                    String m = folio.getString(i);
                    Log.v("M" + i, m);
                    image_urls1 .add(folio.getString(i) + ",");//adding here
                    Log("JSON-ARRAY-->" + image_urls1.get(i) ); // printing the current element
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

`true` means that your adding was successful.
You must create additional `for` loop through array in order to fetch added values.
Also this

```
for (int i = 0; i < folio.length(); i++) {
    String m = folio.getString(i);
    Log.v("M" + i, m);
    image_urls.add(folio.getString(i) + ",");
    Log("JSON-ARRAY-->" + image_urls.add(folio.getString(i)));
}
```

will create three `StringBuilder` objects on every iteration due to string concatenation.